# add a .pdf file(.png basically) to the end of every page in another .pdf file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, pdftk

I have a code.ps file converted to code.pdf , which I want to add to the end of every page in my test.pdf , i.e shrink the test.pdf's every page and add an image to the end of it .

I have written the following shell script to it , but it appends the code.pdf as a new page after every page of test.pdf ! ...Kindly help . Here is my code :-

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=test.pdf
pages="`pdftk $filename dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d : -f2`"
numpages=`for ((a=1; a <= $pages; a++)); do echo -n "A$a B1 "; done`
pdftk A=$filename B=code.pdf cat $numpages output $filename-alternated.pdf
exit 0
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly a simple pdfnup call should fit your needs!

Comment: Yes , I tried pdfnup ,but essentially it only merges the two pages into one , and perhaps there is no concept of adjusting the ratios of the the pages in the new one , as in, my problem can be better stated as the following : EXCEPT FOR CPDF , Is there any utility to 'STAMP' a .pdf/ .pdf file at the end of every page of ANOTHER .PDF FILE?

Comment: `pdftk` has a `stamp` (or `background` option) - but it simply overlays the two pdfs. I would use `pdfjam` to preprocess the test.pdf (scale and offest) and `pdftk` to compose them. This would require only two lines of code (three if code.pdf has to be preprocessed as well) and no loops.

Comment: If you can be more specific on the format or the pdfs I can construct an answer.

Comment: Yes!In the answer you gave ,, I want the image to be contained well within the borders of the original page,and at the end of the page .What I have created thus far is an image stamped at the end of the page but overlapping with some text over there !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple example of stamping an image (image.[pdf,png] onto a multipage pdf (text.pdf) allowing for manual tweaking of the scaling and offsets using `pdfjam` and `pdftk` could be:

```bash
# scale and offset the text part
pdfjam --scale 0.8 --frame True --offset '0cm 2.5cm' text.pdf
# scale and offset the image
pdfjam --paper 'a4paper' --scale 0.3 --offset '7cm -12cm' image.pdf
# combine both
pdftk text-pdfjam.pdf stamp image-pdfjam.pdf output combined.pdf
```

This might look like
[image]

If you start with an image file (png, jpg) you can convert it to pdf using imagemagick like

```
convert image.png image.pdf
```

Of course, the scale factors and offsets have to be adjusted to your needs. I included the `--frame` option to highlight the scaling of the text.pdf part. The `stamp` option overlays the image, whereas the `background` option would underlay the image.

Comment: Thankyou ,, Yes I lately tried kinda a similar thing , But thankyou so Much Jacob :) ...can we by any means remove the borders in the original page so as to make it look like a real new A4 page ?

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH Jakob!!!!Got what I wanted :) Wish I had a few repo points to upvote such lovely answer ! Thanks Once again brother!

Comment: To get rid of the border, simply remove the `--frame True` option in the first pdfjam call. - You may accept the answer, to finalize this question.

Comment: @Jakob how do I use coordinates to place the image at a particular location on the page

Comment: @Daniel `pdfjam` uses the LaTeX pdfpages pages, thus the [docu](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) is a good place to start. Here, the `offset` command is used to shift the image from the center of the page. Hope this can help you.